# Explain this Zend_Select and Convert to SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

```
$select->from(array('u'=>'user'),array('count'=>'distinct count(*)'))
                   ->joinLeft(
                        array('d' => 'details'),
                        'u.detailsid = d.detailsid',
                        array());
```

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM user
LEFT JOIN details ON
details.detailsid = user.detailsid;
```

But where does the `count` fit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(*) AS count FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN details AS d ON
d.detailsid = u.detailsid;
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

> In the second argument of the from() method, you can specify the columns to select from the respective table. If you specify no columns, the default is "*", the SQL wildcard for "all columns" […] You can list the columns in a simple array of strings, or as an associative mapping of column alias to column name. If you only have one column to query, and you don't need to specify a column alias, you can list it as a plain string instead of an array.

On a side note, you can simply echo the query to see what it would produce (same page as above):

> Converting a Select Object to a SQL String - If you need access to a string representation of the SQL query corresponding to the `Zend_Db_Select` object, use the `__toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck, and want an easy to turn your Zend_Db_Select object into an SQL query, you can do this:

```
echo $select;
```

This is really handy when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For Using counts you need to use `Zend_Db_Expr`

```
$select->from(array('u'=>'user'),array('count'=> new Zend_Db_Expr("distinct count(*)"))
               ->joinLeft(
                    array('d' => 'details'),
                    'u.detailsid = d.detailsid',
                    array());
```

I am guessing that's what you asked.

Comment: From the [Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html): *Using Zend_Db_Expr for column names is not necessary if your column expression contains parentheses; Zend_Db_Select recognizes parentheses and treats the string as an expression, skipping quoting and correlation names.*

Comment: @Gordon That's good to know, i haven't had luck with that in personal experience. I had always Wrap my `count` in a `Zend_Db_Expr` Thanks for the note.